# Cannot access files contained inside a zip file uploaded to the server using $_FILES

Tags: php, xml, zip

I'm currently uploading a zip file to the server using the below code:

```
<div id = 'imfContainer'>
    <?php include('../menu.php'); ?>
    <div id='imfContentWrapper'>
        <div id='imfContent'>
            <div id='stylized' class='myform'>
                <form action='multibackwardCompatible2.php' method='post' onSubmit='return validateForm()' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                    <h1>Validate Backward Compatibility for Multiple Models</h1>
                    <p>
                        Select a zip file containing the models you wish to test for backward compatibility. These will be tested against the latest model with the same name in the repository. 
                    </p>
                    <table id='project_register_form'>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Models Zip File <span style='color:red;'>*</span></th>
                            <td>
                                <input type='file' name ='modelZip[]' id='modelZip'><BR CLEAR=LEFT>
                                <span id='up_error' class='error_message'></span>
                            </td>
                            <td class='comment'>    
                                <span id='spanButtonPlaceHolder'></span>
                                <div id='divStatus'></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                    </table>
                    <input type='hidden' name='backward_compatible2' id='backward_compatible2' value='true' />                  
                    <button type='submit'>Validate BC</button>
                </form>
                <p></p>
                <div id='status' style="display:none; position:relative;"><img src="../images/eindicator.gif" alt="Smiley face" /></div>
                <div id='report'>
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['backward_compatible2'])){
                    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
                    $message = compatibilityResult();

                }
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include('../footer.php'); ?>
</div>
```

These zip files will contain a number of xml files, what I want to do is once the zip file is submitted to get each xml file out of the zip file and compare them with other xml files I have on the server. The problem is I cant figure out how to get files out of the zip files because they are stored as .tmp files when using $_FILES global variables to store the zip file in.

This is my php code below:

```
function compatibilityResult(){

    include('../logAction.php');
    include('reportFilter.php');

    if ($_FILES['modelZip']['type'][0]=="application/x-zip-compressed") {
        $filename = $_FILES["modelZip"]["name"];
        $source = $_FILES["modelZip"]["tmp_name"];
        $type = $_FILES["modelZip"]["type"];
        //print_r($filename);
        //print_r($source);
        //print_r($type);
        //print $_FILES['model']['tmp_name'][0];

    }
}
```

I've tried using code in my php such as http://snipplr.com/view/69947/ but no luck. Is there any way using $_FILES to get the xml files out of the zip that has been uploaded?

Comment: You should be able to use the `ZipArchive` class to unzip: http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Comment: Hi was trying to do it with ziparchive but don't think it will help in this case, when the user uploads the zip file to the server I don't want to extract it to their local machine to access the xml files, I just want to access the xml files in the zip folder on the server without extracting them anywhere do you know if thats possible? The zip file is currently stored as a .tmp file in the $_FILES variable

Comment: The zip archive will extract to where ever you want. It can extract to the server if that is where you want to extract to. If you want to move or manipulate the file, try `$zip = file_get_contents($_FILES["modelZip"]["tmp_name"]);` Now the file should be stored in your `$zip` variable, you can save it or extract it to your server using ziparchive or whatever you'd like to do.